# I can't run my UWP c# App in Kiosk Mode on Windows 10

Tags: c#, uwp, kiosk-mode

I have developed a UWP app in C# which runs fine when debugging. I want to prevent users from being able to close it, so want to use kiosk mode.

Every time I try to set this app to run in kiosk mode through control panel I get the error message: "We weren't able to start your app. Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to sign out, or contact your system admin. For more info, search online for error code: 0x80073cfb"

I have searched for this error and it seems to have something to do with windows store? At least that's all I can find. I've tried turning developer options on and off in windows 10, but it doesn't make any difference.

I haven't installed it manually for a user, i've just used the app that visual studio copies over to the remote machine. I dont know if this will complicate anything?!

I have tried searching for an answer on this forum, and online, but i can't find anything that is the same problem i'm experiencing.

Thank you in advance

Andrew

Comment: The error code means that your package has been installed in the device already and reinstallation of the package was blocked. You might need to check your device and uninstall the previous version of your app.

Comment: ok thanks, i didn't realise that it installed the app again. thanks for the help. i will give that a go :)

Comment: Sure, if you still have the problem, please let me know.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT In kiosk mode we will setup only one application. Definitely that application will be installed in the admin user account. So in this case what should i do to get this issue resolved?

Comment: @AndrewTaylor How did you fix the issue. I am running into exactly same problem. I want to run a UWP in kiosk mode and I am using Visual studio to deploy one of the sample programs on local machine. The program runs fine when I deploy and debug it locally. I see the same error as you, when I try to run the program in Kiosk mode after installation. I would greatly appreciate any help on this